# Probability of event A happening is 0.53. What is the probability of event A occuring 4 times in a row over 63 samples?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am working on a personal project where I need the probability of the following scenario:

There are 53 blue balls and 47 red balls in a bag. If I draw 63 balls from the bag (with replacement), what is the probability that a blue ball will be drawn 4 times in a row at least once?

The 'in a row' part of this question is throwing me off, I can't seem to figure out how to think about this.

Update: I wrote a little python script to simulate this scenario, resulting in an average occurrence rate of 93.7% over 1 million simulations. Though I am very interested in the math behind this for verification.

Comment: Doing it exactly seems messy (unless I am missing something).  Two ways to approximate it:  Method I, it's easier if $P(A)=.5$ since then every path has the same probability as any other path of the same length. Method 2, you can use indicator variables to get the mean and variance of the number of times you get four in a row so you can use a normal approximation (Or just use the mean and assume a Poisson process for the number.)

Comment: Note:  I don't think the Poisson approximation is terrible accurate, perhaps the normal is better (though I would check that method in the $P(A)=.5$ case).

Comment: Just ran the normal approximation and got $.9334$ which appears to align nicely with the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the exact figure with a recurrence:

Let $f(n,k)$ be the probability that after $n$ draws with replacement you have not seen four consecutive blue balls but you have seen the last $k$ balls blue.  You then have

$$f(0,0)=1$$
$$f(0,1)=f(0,2)=f(0,3)=0$$
$$f(n,1)=0.53 f(n-1,0)$$
$$f(n,2)=0.53 f(n-1,1)=0.53^2 f(n-2,0)$$
$$f(n,3)=0.53 f(n-1,2)=0.53^3 f(n-3,0)$$
$$f(n,0)=0.47 (f(n-1,0)+f(n-1,1)+f(n-1,2)+f(n-1,3)) \\ =0.47 (f(n-1,0)+0.53 f(n-2,0)+0.53^2 f(n-3,0)+0.53^3 f(n-4,0))$$

The probability you want is $$1-f(63,0)-f(63,1)-f(63,2)-f(63,3) \\= 1 -\tfrac{1}{0.47}f(64,0)$$ and if you apply the recurrence you get about $0.9367376$, close to the simulation

Comment: Nicely done, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n$ denote the ways to draw 4 successive blue balls in $n$ draws.

Now let $d$ be a drawing of $n$ balls in which we have 4 successive blue balls. Then no matter how we extend $d$, we still have 4 successive blue balls.

On the other hand, the only drawings in $A_{n+1}$ which are not obtained by extending a drawing from $A_n$ are those where in the first $n$ balls, there is no occurence of 4 blue balls, however the last 4 balls $n-2,n-1,n,n+1$ are all blue. From this also follows, that the ball $n-3$ has to be red. 
So we can just take any drawing in $A_{n-4}^C$, i.e. any drawing of $n-4$ ball that contains no 4 successive blue balls, and add 1 red, and 4 blue balls to its end.

So we have

$$
A_{n+1}= \{w\hat\times \{0,1\}\mid w\in A_n\}\,\,\dot\cup \,\,\{w\hat\times (0,1,1,1,1)\mid w\in A_{n-4}^C\}
$$
(where we define $A\hat\times B$ as the set $A\times B$, but with each element flattened; The $\dot\cup$ means it's a disjoint union)

Therefore we have:

$$
\mathbb P (A_{n+1})= \mathbb P(\{w\hat\times \{0,1\}\mid w\in A_n\})\,\,+ \,\,\mathbb P(\{w\hat\times (0,1,1,1,1)\mid w\in A_{n-4}^C\})
\\ = \mathbb P(A_n) + (1-\mathbb P(A_{n-4}))\cdot \frac{47\cdot 53^4}{100^5}
$$

Add in the start cases $\mathbb P(A_1)=\mathbb P(A_2)=\mathbb P(A_3)=0, \mathbb P(A_4) = \frac{53^4}{100^4}, \mathbb P(A_5) = 2\cdot \frac{53^4\cdot 47}{100^5} + \frac{53^5}{100^5}$, and you obtain
$$ \mathbb P(A_{63}) = 0.9367376$$

Python code:

```
f_dict = dict()


def f(n):
    try:
        return f_dict[n]
    except KeyError:
        if (n > 5):
            f_dict[n] = f(n - 1) + (1-f(n - 5)) * (47 * 53 ** 4) / 100 ** 5
            return f(n)
        elif (n == 5):
            f_dict[n] = 2 * (53 / 100) ** 4 * (47 / 100) + (53 / 100) ** 5
            return f(n)
        elif (n == 4):
            f_dict[n] = (53 / 100) ** 4
            return f(n)
        else:
            return 0


print(f(63))
```